# TCP server listen and client listen windows software

Tags: port, tcp, relay

I am using Windows OS on an amazon cloud AWS with static public IP.
On this machine I need to set up a TCP server to listen on port 2204 for raw data that will arrive from a GPS base station over TCP protocol.
When the data arrives at  port 2204 I need the software to make that data available in TCP client mode on port 2207

I have tried various software packages without success.
I would prefer to work in GUI type interface rather than command line if possible.

Any ideas please

Louis

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'nc' command, it comes with cygwin

```
nc -l 2204 | nc 127.0.0.1 2207
```

or this port remapper has a GUI http://www.kmint21.com/free/
[image]

```
pm.exe <lp> <rip> <rp> [w] [h]
  lp - local port
  rip - remote ip
  rp - remote port
  w - write log
  h - hidden mode
```

or ssh making a connection to yourself 127.0.0.1  and forward to wherever (ssh -L) tunneling. So you set up a local ssh server. Then you connect to it `ssh -L 2204:127.0.0.1:2207 user@127.0.0.1`  And then one side of the connection will listen and the other side(the ssh server side) will forward to that ip:port. So your local computer is listening on port 2204 and the remote machine is forwarding to 127.0.0.1:2207

Comment: Hi Barlop just to clarify I need it to send the data to port 2207 on the same machine i.e 2204 and 2207 same IP address.  Louis

Comment: @LouisMullen  oh yeah, I just corrected that. 127.0.0.1 as your IP means the same machine.